# Как запустить sublime text с консоли mac os x?

Tags: bash, macos, sublime-text

Какая версия sublime-text у меня не знаю, нигде не пишет в редакторе версию.

Вот содержимое ошибки:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/user_one/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Версия - Help --> About Sublime Text . Там внизу есть Build XXXX

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: попробовал  вроде без ошибок прошло запускаю sublime index.php Но к сожалению получаю              bash: sublime: command not found         (   Mac OS X EL Capitan)

Comment: Нужно писать так: `subl index.php`, но если вам удобней через `sublime`, тогда замените в команде, которая выше, в конце `subl` на `sublime`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Comment: @z3000 может тогда ответ отметите, как решение? )